# Highlight Duplicate Rows from 4 column with single row

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, duplicates, syntax-highlighting, conditional-formatting

I'm new for google sheet as well as excel but Please find the  [google sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rdZTDeTXl3vkT_hzPiYRRYwT3dw_zphokoKlqOmreTw/edit?usp=sharing) (i share it with editable) so you can edit also. So, my question is Ï want to highlight column A,B with Column D,E (for find duplicate) but don't want highlight row 3 and row 4 (it's duplicate but i want to highlight and compare between column A, with D and column B wit E.

Sorry for the poor English but hope you guys understand.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `my question is Ï want to highlight column A,B with Column D,E (for find duplicate) but don't want highlight row 3 and row 4 (it's duplicate but i want to highlight and compare between column A, with D and column B wit E.`. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect as the image?

Comment: Don't add details in comments. Instead, [edit] your post using the link below the tags, so that the information is in the question where it can be seen.

Comment: @SagarRana can you explain further why you don't want to highlight row 3 and row 4? Can you at least share images or screenshots of the expected output?

Comment: It's already solved by @player1 BTW I don't want 3 persons with same name or amount highlight (for found out which customer put different money or not match with our database)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=(COUNTIF($A$2:$A&$B$2:$B, $D2&$E2)>0)*($A2<>"")
```

[image]

Comment: thank you so much it working for me and thank you for edit and keep the formula. Thank you so much. BTW what if I want to highlight non-duplicate or unique one? If can humble request (same condition but not highlight duplicate, only highlight unique or those cells which one unique or non matching with others. 
Thank You so much... Huge Respect

Comment: @SagarRana try: `=NOT((COUNTIF($A$2:$A&$B$2:$B, $D2&$E2)>0))*($A2<>"")`

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH.... No words for thanking you more than just this 'THANK YOU" words. It's working... Thank you so much... RESPECT